# How to inspect the status of a shared memory?

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

I am currently exploring local IPC using shared memories because certain data sizes cannot be transmitted quickly through named pipes. To achieve this, I am relying on techniques such as `shmget`, `shmop`, `shmat`, and `shmctl`.

It is not clear to me how to monitor the status of shared memory from the [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmget.2.html). **Particularly, I wish to know if the data is being written, has already been written in its entirety, and if it is safe to read or write to the shared memory.**

If it were about the same process, I could have used internal semaphores. But this is for letting two different processes communicate. I do not know how to maintain a semaphore between them.

**EDIT** More specifically, I'd like to interop python and another language X. In some requests, X may send more than a million arrays to python. I want this transmission to be as fast as possible. The runtime of python and the runtime of X are completely different process. Neither is the parent of the other, and neither is embedded in the other. But they do run on the same machine.

Comment: Are you using threads (e.g. `pthread_create`) or processes (e.g. `fork`)?

Comment: If you have multiple processes and a shared memory segment you will need a semaphore to control access to the shared memory.  For the shared memory you need shmget, shmat, shmop, shmdt, and shmctl.  For the shared memory you need semget, semop, semdt, and semctl.  The use of the two things is very similar.  I could make an answer but it would be very big if I included a bunch of source code.

Comment: There are two types of semaphores: SysV (e.g. `semget` et. al.) and Posix(?) (`sem_init` et. al.). SysV will work but [IIRC] they must call into the kernel. The posix semaphores will be faster. The only wrinkle is that the first arg to `sem_init` has to point to a shared memory area [that you get from `shmat`]. With a suitable struct that you devise, you can use _one_ shared memory area for everything. But, perhaps easier, is to have one [shared] area for the semaphores and one [or more] areas for your data buffers.

Comment: @CraigEstey I may have missed something as I'm not familiar with the field. I'm trying to interopt two languages via shm. As a result, they are completely different processes that do not share a common run time (so for example they are not threads in the same C program). In such case, can I still use semaphores? If you (or someone) would, could you provide some tiny examples or keywords I can read about?

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html

Comment: Interopt two _languages_? As in, C and python? You'd need to have a way convert data types: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html Do you really mean two _programs_? You talked about using named pipes [but too slow]. So that we understand your data structures, maybe some sample code? Do you have fixed or variable size buffers? How does one process generate data and how frequently? What does the other process do with it? What do the programs do? Please edit your _question_ and post this stuff.